# Consuming WCFREST Service from Windows Phone 8 using WebClient

Tags: windows-phone-8, async-await, webclient, wcf-rest

with the reference to the [Link](http://www.ganshani.com/2011/08/wcf-rest-services-for-windows-phone-2.)

I am getting an error while running the application.
I am unable to find the solution to the problem.

[image: Runtime Error during button click]

Comment: What does InnerException say?

Comment: Its reaching DownloadStringCompleted so did you get a call at your webservice end? What are you returning from service?

Comment: On Windows Phone 8 the `WebClient` supports Task-Based asynchronous programming (see the **TaskAsync** suffixed methods). However, the [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx "HttpClient Class") (that you can get it from the [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries") **NuGet** package) is better suited for asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

May be you getting error because you are trying to call web service from local host. Host your web service some where in Http(Url). Windows phone emulator doesn't allow to call service from local host.

Comment: The above problem is resolved by changing the url of the sevice from localhost to qualified ip address.

Comment: Here I am facing the issue with serializer in the same code.